# Looped Jquery slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I created a slider from 5 elements but can't understand how to loop this slider. I need the slider continue moving from right to left when I click left tick and from left to right when I click right tick even when the last slide have been shown.

Jsfiddle with the code to test - [Jsfiddle](http://codepen.io/Evgenylad/pen/peLJbM)

My HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__viewport">

    <button class="slider__btn slider__btn--left" type="button" name="button"
          @click="previousSlide">
    </button>

    <ul class="slider__slides" data-current="0">
      <li class="slider__slide slider__slide--hiddenLeft">
        <img class="slider__img" src="../../img/slide1.png" alt="1">
        <h3 class="slider__title">
        Левый слайд
        </h3>
       <span class="slider__date">21 февраля 2017</span>
      </li>

      <li class="slider__slide slider__slide--left">
        <img class="slider__img" src="../../img/slide2.png" alt="1">
        <h3 class="slider__title">
        Левый слайд
        </h3>
        <span class="slider__date">25 февраля 2017</span>
      </li>

      <li class="slider__slide slider__slide--current">
        <img class="slider__img" src="../../img/slide3.png" alt="2">
        <h3 class="slider__title">
        Текущий слайд
        </h3>
       <span class="slider__date">27 февраля 2017</span>
      </li>

      <li class="slider__slide slider__slide--right">
        <img class="slider__img" src="../../img/slide4.png" alt="3">
        <h3 class="slider__title">
        Правый слайд
        </h3>
       <span class="slider__date">28 февраля 2017</span>
      </li>

      <li class="slider__slide slider__slide--hidden">
        <img class="slider__img" src="../../img/slide5.png" alt="4">
        <h3 class="slider__title">
        Скрытый слайд
        </h3>
        <span class="slider__date">29 февраля 2017</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <button class="slider__btn slider__btn--right" type="button" name="button"
          @click="nextSlide">
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JS

```
  $('.slider__btn--left').click(function() {  
    console.log('test')
    var slideWidth = 620
    var currentSlide = parseInt($('.slider__slides').data('current'))
    currentSlide++
    var size = $('.slider__slides').children().length
    if (currentSlide >= (size - 3)) {
      currentSlide = 1
   }
    console.log(currentSlide)
    console.log('size', size)
   $('.slider__slides').animate({left: currentSlide * slideWidth},   300).data('current', currentSlide)
 });

$('.slider__btn--right').click(function() {  
  var slideWidth = 620
  var currentSlide = parseInt($('.slider__slides').data('current'))
  currentSlide--
  var size = $('.slider__slides').children().length
  if (currentSlide <= (-size + 3)) {
    console.log(currentSlide)
    currentSlide = -1
  }
  console.log('size', size)
  console.log(currentSlide)
  $('.slider__slides').animate({left: currentSlide * slideWidth},    300).data('current', currentSlide)
});
```

Comment: That's a Codepen, not a JSFiddle. :P Anyways, I fixed it up for you. Good luck on whatever it's a part of!

Comment: Thanks, but where I could see fixed version?

Comment: My [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927771/looped-jquery-slider/42928525#42928525), right below. If it works for you, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark under the up/down-vote buttons so it turns green. This will help others find the right answer and give both of us reputation points, giving us access to features that allow us to make Stack Overflow a better place.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I need siblings of the current slide to be partly visible as at my example.
Here is the link for the one are similar to those I need - [EXAMPLE](https://msk.kassir.ru/)

Comment: Alright, I'll fix it in a few hours when I'm not at school. :P

Comment: @Feathercrown Trying to clone elements and add it `$(cloned).prependTo('.slider__slides')` but not too successful

Comment: I think I have an idea for how to do this, but only if 1. The new images don't have to slide, they can just sort of teleport, and 2. The two images on either side can be shown fully, not cut off (I *might* be able to do it with only constraint #1)

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions to check if your currentSlide value was out of bounds were always returning true, resulting in the slide not changing.

Also, please use semicolons. please. :P

Note that I changed some formatting on your page and the image sources; this was for debugging purposes, and you can change it back if you want. I also had to change the sliding to appearing/disappearing for testing purposes (the testing environment provided by Stack Overflow has too small of a result window to see the results as you test it).

```js
var currentSlide=1;
$('.slider__slides').children().eq(currentSlide-1).siblings().hide();

$('.slider__btn--left').click(function() {  
    var slideWidth = 620;
    var currentSlide = parseInt($('.slider__slides').data('current'));
    currentSlide++;
    var size = $('.slider__slides').children().length;
    if (currentSlide > size) {
      currentSlide = 1;
   }
  console.clear();
  console.log(currentSlide);
  $('.slider__slides').children().eq(currentSlide-1).show();
  $('.slider__slides').children().eq(currentSlide-1).siblings().hide();
  $('.slider__slides').data('current', currentSlide);
 });

$('.slider__btn--right').click(function() {  
  var slideWidth = 620;
  var currentSlide = parseInt($('.slider__slides').data('current'));
  currentSlide--;
  var size = $('.slider__slides').children().length;
  if (currentSlide <= 0) {
    currentSlide = size;
  }
  console.clear();
  console.log(currentSlide);
  $('.slider__slides').children().eq(currentSlide-1).show();
  $('.slider__slides').children().eq(currentSlide-1).siblings().hide();
  $('.slider__slides').data('current', currentSlide);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__viewport">

    <button class="slider__btn slider__btn--left" type="button" name="button">Left
    </button>
    
    <button class="slider__btn slider__btn--right" type="button" name="button">Right
    </button>
    
    <ul class="slider__slides" data-current="0">
      <li class="slider__slide slider__slide--hiddenLeft">
        <img class="slider__img" src="http://images.huffingtonpost.com/2012-08-18-GorillaSilverback6.jpg" alt="1" width="100" height="100">
        <h3 class="slider__title">
        Левый слайд
        </h3>
       <span class="slider__date">21 февраля 2017</span>
      </li>

      <li class="slider__slide slider__slide--left">
        <img class="slider__img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" alt="2" width="100" height="100">
        <h3 class="slider__title">
        Левый слайд
        </h3>
        <span class="slider__date">25 февраля 2017</span>
      </li>

      <li class="slider__slide slider__slide--current">
        <img class="slider__img" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg" alt="3" width="100" height="100">
        <h3 class="slider__title">
        Текущий слайд
        </h3>
       <span class="slider__date">27 февраля 2017</span>
      </li>

      <li class="slider__slide slider__slide--right">
        <img class="slider__img" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/image-slider-2.jpg" alt="4" width="100" height="100">
        <h3 class="slider__title">
        Правый слайд
        </h3>
       <span class="slider__date">28 февраля 2017</span>
      </li>

      <li class="slider__slide slider__slide--hidden">
        <img class="slider__img" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/wallpaper-sunset-images-back-217159.jpg" alt="5" width="100" height="100">
        <h3 class="slider__title">
        Скрытый слайд
        </h3>
        <span class="slider__date">29 февраля 2017</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```